# php - SQL week of year() to string/date

Tags: mysql, date, php

I run a query against a MySQL database to get total number of visits grouped by week.
The structure of the table is:

`|ID (int) | SESSION (char) | TIMESTAMP (datetime) |`

My query looks like this:
`'SELECT COUNT(session), WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) 
FROM stats 
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC';`

So I get an array of week numbers eg 40,41,45 etc, along with the view count.

How can I convert this into readable date (using PHP)? It's not practical to say, "Week number 40-something: 2000 visits".

I'm looking for something in the form of StartDate-EndDate/Month/Year, eg. Week 5-11/12/2011, Visits: XXXX.

Any functions you might have used before? I've tried but with no luck.

Is my SQL query a correct way to do it? Assuming that I'm querying the db correctly for what I'm trying to accomplish, is there a way to convert a week number into a day/date span?

I'm also wondering what will happen if a week spans between two months or even two years.

Comment: -1, I don't think this make any sense. From what I understand, to return a dayofweek in mysql, the data source need to be a date as well. So, you are missing a big chunk of critical information. You should revise again your question.

Comment: @ajreal is it better now? I'm not sure what else to include. I thought it should have been somewhat common. Perhaps I'm not thinking it right?

Comment: Yes, without that piece of information (schema) is almost not possible to get a understanding of your question. OK, back to your question, because your source is timestamp (that's mean you can return any format) **BUT** you are using a **GROUP BY**. (aggregate function). I think is not possible ... or you can add more example of input and your desired output.

Comment: Add some sample data and expected data output based on that sample data.. In your example `Week 5-11/12/2011` -- is 11/12/2011 the minimum date? Maximum? How did you derive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Assumptions:

- The date you want to display is the Monday Week Date for that week
- Your main output is `Week <week number>-<monday date of week>, Visits: <count>.`
- You know enough PHP to be able to pull the column `Phrase`

The following SQL command should display for you the count of sessions per week of year, the week of year, and your desired phrase:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(session) AS VisitCount
    , WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) AS WeekOfYear_Value
    , MAKEDATE(
        CASE 
            WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) = 52 
                THEN YEAR(timestamp)-1 
            ELSE YEAR(timestamp) 
        END, (WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) * 7)-4) AS DateOfWeek_Value
    , CONCAT('Week ', WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)
        , '-', MAKEDATE(
            CASE 
                WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) = 52 
                    THEN YEAR(timestamp)-1 
                ELSE YEAR(timestamp) 
            END, (WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) * 7)-4) -- Monday
        , ', Visits: ' , COUNT(session), '.') AS Phrase
FROM stats
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Try it out on your existing data.

[edit : additional code changes]

To get you the Sunday output:

```
SELECT COUNT(session) AS VisitCount
    , WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) AS WeekOfYear_Value
    , CONCAT('Week ', WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)
        , '-', MAKEDATE(
            CASE 
                WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) = 52 
                    THEN YEAR(timestamp)-1 
                ELSE YEAR(timestamp) 
            END, 
            CASE 
                WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) = 52 
                    THEN (WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) * 7)+3
                ELSE (WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp) * 7)+2
            END
            )
    , ', Visits: ' , COUNT(session), '.') AS Phrase
FROM stats
GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Also notice that this last update includes another `CASE` in the `makedate` command, to ensure consistency between dates from the current and last year values.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Yeap, from then on I know how to get and display what I need. Thanks a lot Nonym.

Comment: Great! Just to note; the `case` statement is so that if the week of year is 52, we make sure that the `makedate` command uses the previous year instead of the current year to avoid a week `2011-01-01` point to the week of year `2011-12-26`. Also, I used `-4` to point to Monday, thinking that that might be the way to declare the week.

Comment: Instead of getting the first day of each week, how can I get the last? Because I visualize the data on a continuous XY graph (X being the dates-mondays, Y being the visits), the graph seems a bit off. For example, for the following values: week 1-7->1000, week 7-14->1500, week 14-21->500, the following points are created a(1, 1000), b(1, 1500), c(1, 500). If you connect them it seems like the visits actually go down the second week instead of up! So instead of the first day of the week, I need to summarize the visits of the previous 7 days and associate them with the last day of the week!

Comment: I've updated my post to include Sunday output :) Hope this one does the trick!